# Parameters notify in share is not working (Gspread)

Tags: gspread

Hi I have a python code in google colab that create a google spreadsheet and share this file by don't send email this is my code.

```
wb.share('Email', perm_type='user', role='reader',notify=False)
```

but when run this code is still send the email.
How can I run this cell without send the email?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

yes this is a known issue, it has recently been fixed, but not released yet.

See PR: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/pull/1107

It will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks ! Lavigne, Now this parameter return to normal.